# How to show the entire table of contents, step by step, in a Beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I'd like to show the entire table of contents of my presentation, step by step, section after section. To do this, I think I have to rearrange this part of my preamble as it appears below in my MWE: `\AtBeginSubsection[]`

How could I fix that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{\hspace*{3em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsubsection\par}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection,
  sectionstyle=show/show,
  subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,
  subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded,
]
\end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{outline}
\tableofcontents    
\end{frame}

\section{Section title}
\begin{frame}{Section frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsection frame}
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsubsection frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to have the TOC step-by-step all at the beginning of the presentation, or at each new section the TOC with all entries up to and including this section?

Comment: At each new section the toc with all entries up to and including this section.

Comment: This sort of sounds like the minitoc package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: as you can see in the MWE, there are some wrong code I have to fix (subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded,), but how?

Comment: The beamer manual says that it uses a standard \tableofcontents, which take no arguments.  You can adjust the tocdepth counter, but that is abut it.

Answer (score 2):

**At each new section the toc with all entries up to and including this section.**

```
\AtBeginSection
{
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[sections={1-\thesection}]
\end{frame}
}
```

**The overall code**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{\hspace*{3em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsubsection\par}

%\AtBeginSubsection[]
\AtBeginSection
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
    sections={1-\thesection},
%   currentsection,
%   sectionstyle=show/show,
%   subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,
%   subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded,
]
\end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First section title}
\begin{frame}{Section frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsection frame}
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsubsection frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Second section title}
\begin{frame}{Section frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsection frame}
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsubsection frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Third section title}
\begin{frame}{Section frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsection frame}
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsubsection frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to show every current section at the beginning of each section (sub and subsubsection including).